# Installing extra_requires with tox

Tags: pip, setuptools, pytest, tox

If I want to install extra requirements for the package being tested with Tox who would I do it?

E.g. If I am testing a package called Websauna and I want to instal

```
  websauna[test]
```

Instead of

```
  websauna
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In tox.ini:

```
[testenv]
extras = test
```

[Documentation](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#confval-extras=MULTI-LINE-LIST)